# pyspark feed one RDD to another using the 'in' clause

Tags: pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark RDD (`myRDD`) that is a variable-length list of IDs, such as

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d','f'], ['g', 'h', 'i','j']]
```

I have a pyspark dataframe (`myDF`) with columns `ID` and `value`.

I want to query `myDF` with the query:

```
outputDF = myDF.select(F.collect_set("value")).alias("my_values").where(col("ID").isin(id_list))
```

where `id_list` is an element from the `myRDD`, such as ['d','f'] or ['a', 'b', 'c'].

An example would be:

```
outputDF = myDF.select(F.collect_set("value")).alias("my_values").where(col("ID").isin(['d','f']))
```

What is a parallelizable way to use the RDD to query the DF like this?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your dataframe column "ID" is of type `stringType()`, you want to keep ID values that appear in any of your RDD's row.

First, let's transform our RDD into a one column dataframe with with a unique ID for each row:

```py
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
ID_df = hc.createDataFrame(
    myRDD.map(lambda row: [row]), 
    ['ID']
).withColumn("uniqueID", psf.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

We'll explose it so that each row only has one ID value:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
ID_df = ID_df.withColumn('ID', psf.explode(ID_df.ID))
```

We can now join out original dataframe, the inner join will serve as a filter:

```py
myDF = myDF.join(ID_df, "ID", "inner)
```

A `collect_set` is an aggregation function, so you need so kind of `groupBy` before using it, for instance by the newly created row ID:

```py
myDF.groupBy("uniqueID").agg(
    psf.collect_set("ID").alias("ID")
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Marie.  This works with one exception: if I feed it [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d','f'], I get back the joined values for both the element ['a', 'b', 'c'] and the element ['d','f'].  The reason I was thinking of using the "in" clause, was because it would only return matching values for that particular element.  The hope was to create a dataframe like [(['a','b','c'],('v1','v2','v3','v4','v5')] where v1 to v5 are all of the values that match to the IDs a, b, and c.

Comment: You can create a unique ID for each row to identify them later. I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, again, @Marie!  I changed the last line to DF.groupBy("uniqueID").agg(psf.collect_set("ID").alias("ID"), psf.collect_set("value").alias("values")).drop("uniqueID") to get the final version of the table i wanted.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: you were so helpful with this, I thought you may be able to help with my latest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289068/pyspark-merge-wrappedarrays-within-a-dataframe